# When in Demon Form, are demons vulnerable to mortal frailties?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

When a Demon is in Demonic Form,
does he gain any intrinsic protection against mundane concerns like
breathing or falling unconscious?

#### In particular, when in Demonic Form do/are demons:

- need to breath?
- immune to poisons?
- fall unconscious? (ie do they stay conscious on full lethal?)
- suffer from wound penalties for having damage in last 3 boxes?
- need to consume food/water?
- need to sleep?

The last two are only really a concern to demons who have burnt their last cover.
However this can happen in play, and is pretty significant for any burnt NPCs.

Is seems odd that a *swarm of glass beetles clinging together into the shape of a man*
might have any issues with being poisoned.
But I can't find it clearly stated,
whereas it is clearly stated in Werewolf (the Forsaken).

Answer (score 8):

You're right; it's never stated explicitly. It does say this:

> In short, a demon’s dual nature affords him **absolutely no special advantages** against the physical needs and afflictions of the world…Over time a demon may develop skills, amass glitches, and recall Embeds that permit him to sidestep these mortal restrictions, but **never again will he experience the total freedom from adversity he possessed as an angel.** (p.182)

The other bit of evidence that we have is what happens to Tilts when demonic form is assumed. Transforming slowly purges tilts related to bodily injury; going loud removes all tilts. (p.195-196). This means that there's something in the act of assuming demonic form that makes things like poison and pain irrelevant, but only in the short term.

You've got evidence to decide either way: my suggestion would be to grant immunity to those things for the scene in which Demonic Form is assumed, but remaining in Demonic Form after the scene concludes allows those kinds of effects to happen again. Seems like a good compromise to me.