# Do Demons in Demonform need to Eat/Drink/Sleep?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

Demonform is quite inhuman.
Fluff-wise, it would not be unreasonable to be, for example, a collection of gleaming steel limbs orbiting a dazzling diamond core, with a glowing, radar-encrusted spun-copper head hovering above.

But I am unsure as to what extent this frees demons from human needs.

Do they need to eat, drink, or sleep?

Can they catch diseases? Or be poisoned?

Obviously, under most circumstances a un-covered demon is going to be under a lot of heat from the God Machine long before starvation or even dying of thirst is a real issue, but I can imagine scenarios where a burned demon might survive days — enough time that thirst could become a real issue. Would it?

Comment: I felt like I had asked this before: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/45401/
Hopefully, now that a few more books have come out, the answer will be clearer.